# Uncaught error : "Can't use asyncStorage in unsigned experience" in expo when user is offline

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to react-native, and built a standalone application using expo, i want to test a specific case where user is offline, but as soon as i open standalone app, it says `Uncaught error : can't user asyncStorage in unsigned experience` without opening the app.

My understanding is that this screen is from expo app, because generally expo will fetch the js bundle from server, and when user is offline expo won't be able to fetch anything, now i want to remove that error.

Please let me know how can i resolve this error.

Comment: did you figure this out? what was the URL of your app you were loading and what model of phone?

Comment: Have you opened a ticket in the Expo forums?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Expo XDE and clearing device cache on android (not clear all data) seems fix this problem for me.